# Run pm2-runtime as non root user in Azure App services

Tags: azure, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service, pm2

Currently I am working on a simple node.js app that needs to be containerized and deployed to Azure linux web app services. (azure app services)

The containerization works fine and the app starts as well in Azure App services.
However, I am running my app as the NODE user to prevent security issues. In general it's good practice to run your app as a non-root user.

While this works fine when you run the app with CMD["node", "start.js"], this won't work with the pm2 library. CMD["pm2-runtime", "start.js"] works on my local machine, but as soon as I push this to the Azure App Service, it just won't boot.

To me this looks like a permissions issue in the Linux environment. Since running PM2 with root works fine in Azure.

#### Dockerfile

````
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake zlib-dev libpng-dev vips-dev git > /dev/null 2>&1
ENV NODE_ENV=production

# Set working directory to /opt/ and copy package.json an yarn.lock in this folder
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn global add node-gyp
RUN yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g && yarn install --production
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Set working directory to /op/app and copy all Strapi related files in this folder
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
#RUN yarn build -> we skip building for now since we do not want to serve the admin panel on production

# Creating the final production image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:18-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache vips-dev
ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /opt/
COPY --from=build /opt/node_modules ./node_modules
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=build /opt/app ./

RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app
RUN chown -R node:node /opt/node_modules
USER node

RUN yarn global add pm2
ENV PM2_PUBLIC_KEY xxxxxxxxxxxxx [hidden for security]
ENV PM2_SECRET_KEY xxxxxxxxxxxx [hidden for security]

# After installing pm2 globally
RUN echo "Global bin directory: $(yarn global bin)"
ENV PATH /home/node/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.config/yarn/global && chown -R node:node /home/node/.config
ENV PATH="/home/node/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:${PATH}"

USER root 
# RUN chown -R node:node /home/node/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin/pm2
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
# RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app/node_modules/.bin/pm2
USER node
EXPOSE 1337

# CMD ls -lah /opt/app && ls -lah /opt/node_modules/.bin && node start.js
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start.js"]```

### Things I've tried so far

- I tried setting different permissions with the "chown" command
- I tried setting the global pm2 package in the NODE users root folder
- I tried setting the ENV PATH to a accessible folder by the NODE user 

Honestly, I tried all sorts of things but none of them seem to work. The annoying part is, that on my local machine all works fine when I spin up the docker container. However as soon as things are in the Azure Cloud, all stops working. And the worst part is that there is 0 errors to be seen, no logging regarding this issue. The only log that is visible is that Azure isn't able to ping my App in time which is logical since PM2 isn't booting up the server.
````

Comment: @Kevin Vugts Did you try running the command in `startup command` in `configuration` in Azure?

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya no I just pushed the image to the Azure Container registry. And this is image is being used by the Linux web appservice of Azure. Which should autostart the docker image. 

The dockerimage works if I don't run it with pm2-runtime but with node instead. Like CMD ["node", "start.js"]. So this indicates to me that this either a permissions issue or an Azure issue.

Since I am able to run it when I disable the "chown" lines in my dockerfile. Then PM2 will be run as root. And everything works fine.

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya any idea?

Answer (score 0):

- The issue you are facing with PM2 in Azure App Service could be due to misconfiguration.
- To resolve this, add the command  `Run pm2 list`  before  `pm2-runtime`  in the `Dockerfile`.
- This command initializes PM2 and sets the proper path for  `pm2-runtime`.

**Modified Dockerfile:**

```
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake zlib-dev libpng-dev vips-dev git > /dev/null 2>&1
ENV NODE_ENV=production
# set working directory to /opt/ and copy package.json an yarn.lock in this folder
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn global add node-gyp
RUN yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g && yarn install --production
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
# set working directory to /op/app and copy all strapi related files in this folder
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
#RUN yarn build -> we skip building for now since we do not want to serve the admin panel on production
# creating the final production image
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:18-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache vips-dev
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY --from=build /opt/node_modules ./node_modules
WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY --from=build /opt/app ./
RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app
RUN chown -R node:node /opt/node_modules
USER node
RUN yarn global add pm2
ENV PM2_PUBLIC_KEY xxxxxxxxxxxxx [hidden for security]
ENV PM2_SECRET_KEY xxxxxxxxxxxx [hidden for security]
# after installing pm2 globally
RUN echo "global bin directory: $(yarn global bin)"
ENV PATH /home/node/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/.pm2
RUN pm2 list # add this command before pm2-runtime
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "start.js"]
```